# ansible throwing error on argument list for os_network

Tags: python, ansible

we have installed ansible version 2.1.0 in ubuntu 14.04.

While using os_network module we are getting this error.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/admin-nfv/Nuage_Automation/nuage_vm_creation/playbooks# ansible-playbook create_or_delete_network.yml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [Create Network] **********************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [create_network : create or delete network] *******************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: create_network() takes at most 4 arguments (7 given)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_crfy0P/ansible_module_os_network.py\", line 247, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_crfy0P/ansible_module_os_network.py\", line 226, in main\n    external, provider, project_id)\nTypeError: create_network() takes at most 4 arguments (7 given)\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @create_or_delete_network.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

-vvv ouput for the error is

```
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_9jY3t3/ansible_module_os_network.py", line 247, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_9jY3t3/ansible_module_os_network.py", line 226, in main
    external, provider, project_id)
TypeError: create_network() takes at most 4 arguments (7 given)

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "os_network"}, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9jY3t3/ansible_module_os_network.py\", line 247, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9jY3t3/ansible_module_os_network.py\", line 226, in main\n    external, provider, project_id)\nTypeError: create_network() takes at most 4 arguments (7 given)\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

And the playbook that we use for creating network is

```
- name: create or delete network
  os_network:
    auth:
      auth_url: "http://1.2.3.4:35357/v2.0"
      username: "admin"
      password: "xxxxxxx"
      project_name: "admin"
    state: "present"
    name: "Test"
    external: true
```

In another machine same code is working without any errors. But not sure whats wrong with the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible uses the `shade` pip package inside the `os_network` module. The interface inside that package, especially around the `create_network` method has changed in recent versions, and newer versions of ansible are now dependent on the new features.

You should make sure you use the latest version on your ansible host, which at the moment is 1.9.0

```
pip install shade==1.9.0
```